# Nesting child selectors in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Foo
            <ul>
                <li>Bar</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to apply CSS only to item "Foo." I do not want to tag every top-level <li> with a special class. My limited knowledge tells me I should be able to do this:

```
.navbar > ul > li  {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

But the style gets applied to "Bar" as well when I do it like this. I thought that '>' specifies only immediate children, does it not work the same way when it's nested? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: try .navbar ul > li:first-child . just guessing here.

Comment: The problem is that the style applies to the *entire* `<li>` (text-transform cascades), and the "child" `<li>` is part of parent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I thought that '>' specifies only immediate children, does it not work the same way when it's nested?

It does work the same way. Since you're anchoring the `ul` directly to `.navbar` with `.navbar > ul`, your selector does apply to `li` elements directly that particular `ul` only.

The problem is not with the selector; it's the fact that [`text-transform`, like most text properties, is inherited by default](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-transform). So even though you're applying the style only to immediate `li` elements, the nested ones receive it by inheritance.

You will need to reverse this manually on the nested elements:

```
.navbar > ul > li li {
    text-transform: none;
}
```